# Is it legal for a 3rd party to clone a drive?

Tags: ssd, clone, legal

I have a 256GB SSD that has my OS, and I want to effectively increase its capacity to 1TB. I contacted a local computer tech to see if he could clone my current SSD onto a new SSD. He initially quoted me a price, but now that I am trying to schedule, he told me he's not sure whether he can legally do this due to software copyright issues.

Are there any legal issues related to doing this? I would try it myself if I had enough hardware. The drive doesn't contain any copyrighted music, movie, or other media files, but does have an OS (windows 8.1) and various software installed (Visual Studio, PhotoShop, etc), which I do have valid licenses for. Also, I do not intend on using the bits in the old SSD after the clone. In fact, I was going to ask the same tech to clone my wife's 7200RPM HDD in her laptop onto the 256GB SSD as long as the first clone was successful and I could use the new 1TB drive as a replacement in my workstation.

Now I know I would be violating several licenses if I took both images of the drive and ran them in separate machines. Of course then I would have to deal with periodic reactivation, etc. The point of my questions is whether it is legal for the 3rd party to perform the cloning service, not knowing how trustworthy I am to do whatever I please after the service is performed.

Comment: Is there some reason why you aren't asking how to do this yourself?  This site isn't for legal opinions or parsing EULAs.  It is for solving tech problems.

Comment: I know I could figure out how to do it myself, but until today I didn't think I had enough hardware (most of my SATA ports are taken up by a RAID 10 array, and I have no other machines other than laptops). But thanks for the downvote, I'll take it if it helps me find expert advice.

Comment: If you can afford a 1tb ssd, can you not afford the ~$20 for a usb sata dock?

Comment: @Zoredache I had no idea such a thing existed at this price. See, downvote totally worth it.

Comment: I like this style http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0099TX7O4

Comment: Yes it's legal, the guy is paranoid.  When you're cloning a hard drive for someone you don't need to know what the bits spell out, just that they were copied properly.  Telling you he won't do it because you might do something bad is dumb, and you should go someplace else.  "I'd sell you this computer, but you might pirate a movie with it, so I can't do it".

Comment: Legal issues and related to such are off topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the worst case licenses are tied to single PC. You're not moving them to another machine and don't plan to use two copies simultaneously, so it's legal.

I've heard of some software that's licensed per hard disk, but that's really weird and unusual.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. The problem the tech is telling me is that I can't be trusted to not violate the copyrights myself, because he doesn't know what I'll do after the clone. Is that enough to protect him for performing the clone as a service to me?

Comment: Having copies is legal as long as you don't use them. There are tons of software that let you image your HDD, effectively making a copy you can use later. Microsoft, Adobe etc. have nothing against it. If that doesn't convince your tech then tell him to confirm that cloning was successful and erase original SSD immediately. ("secure erase" feature can be used to erase SSD without wearing it)

Comment: The problem with that is, I was not going to give him the whole PC. It's large, heavy, and extremely valuable to me. I built it in 2008 in a HAF full tower. So we would not be able to confirm success until I actually got the drive back, plugged it in, and booted. I could give him the whole tower, but would be taking risks transporting it.

Comment: Then let him keep the old drive until you have confirmed that everything works fine.